# How do I create a mapping type for two enums?

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to connect these two types and have mappings:

```
type MappingForEnum<T extends string, A extends string, B extends string> = {
  [key in T]: {[key in A]: B};
  [key in T]: {[key in B]: A};
};

enum Greek {
  ALPHA = 'A',
  BETA = 'B',
}

enum English {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
}

enum types{
  TO_ENGLISH = 'toEnglish',
  TO_GREEK = 'toGreek',
}

const mapping: MappingForEnum<Types, Greek, English> = {
  toEnglish: {
    [Greek.ALPHA]: English.A,
    [Greek.BETA]: English.B,
  },
  toGreek: {
    [English.A]: Greek.ALPHA,
    [English.B]: Greek.BETA,
  },
};
```

How can I modify `MappingForEnum` to get it working?

**Update**

Is there a way to set up this kind of `PureMapping` and wrap it to match what is commented below.

```
type PureMapping = {
  toGreek: Greek,
  toEnglish: English,
};

type Mapping = WrapMapping<PureMapping>;

// type Mapping = {
//   toGreek: MappingForEnum<Greek, English>,
//   toEnglish: MappingForEnum<English, Greek>,
// };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `types` enum cannot be guaranteed to have just two members. Also, there's no way to know which member maps English to Greek and which member maps in reverse. How would this work if `types` had just one member or three?

One solution is to get rid of the first generic type parameter and just rely on hard-coded property names, for example (feel free to choose better names than `convert`/`reverse`):

```
type MappingForEnum<A extends string, B extends string> = {
  convert: {[key in A]: B};
  reverse: {[key in B]: A};
};

...

const mapping: MappingForEnum<Greek, English> = {
  convert: {
    [Greek.ALPHA]: English.A,
    [Greek.BETA]: English.B,
  },
  reverse: {
    [English.A]: Greek.ALPHA,
    [English.B]: Greek.BETA,
  },
};
```

---

Alternatively, you could break the type down into smaller, one-way mappings, and then compose them together:

```
type MappingForEnum<A extends string, B extends string> = { [key in A]: B };

type GreekEnglishMapping = {
  toEnglish: MappingForEnum<Greek, English>;
  toGreek: MappingForEnum<English, Greek>;
};

...

const mapping: GreekEnglishMapping = {
  toEnglish: {
    [Greek.ALPHA]: English.A,
    [Greek.BETA]: English.B,
  },
  toGreek: {
    [English.A]: Greek.ALPHA,
    [English.B]: Greek.BETA,
  },
};
```

Note that with this second solution, it's trivially easy to get a union type similar to your original `types` enum:

```
type supportedMappings = keyof GreekEnglishMapping; // "toEnglish" | "toGreek"
```

---

Here's another approach:

```
type MappingForEnum<A extends string, B extends string> = { [key in A]: B };
type TwoWayMapping<T extends { [0]: string, [1]: string }, A extends string, B extends string> =
    { [key in T[0]]: MappingForEnum<A, B> } &
    { [key in T[1]]: MappingForEnum<B, A> };

type GreekEnglishMapping = TwoWayMapping<[ 'toEnglish', 'toGreek' ], Greek, English>;
```

Sadly, even if you define

```
enum MappingNames {
  toEnglish,
  toGreek,
}
```

Where `MappingNames[0]` is defined at run time, the compiler won't have knowledge of it so the following won't work:

```
type GreekEnglishMapping = TwoWayMapping<MappingNames, Greek, English>;
// Type 'MappingNames' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [0]: string; [1]: string; }'.
```

---

One more stab at it:

```
type MappingForEnum<A extends string, B extends string> = { [key in A]: B };
type TwoWayMapping<T extends { [k: string]: A | B }, A extends string, B extends string> = { 
    [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends A ? MappingForEnum<A, B> : MappingForEnum<B, A>
};

type PureMapping = {
  toEnglish: Greek,
  toGreek: English,
};
type GreekEnglishMapping = TwoWayMapping<PureMapping, Greek, English>;
```

I feel this is probably about as close as you can get to what you were originally asking for. I don't think you can get away from having to specify `Greek`/`English` twice (once in the mapping type and once as generic arguments).

Comment: This is amazing but it still doesn't address the issue still is that I need `toGreek ` and `toEnglish` to be a type that is passed in.

Comment: @ThomasReggi Why do you need it to be passed in, and how do you imagine this working? Like I said at the top of my answer, the fundamental problem with using an enum for this is that the compiler can't ensure how many members are in the enum or know what the purpose of each enum member should be. An enum is simply not expressive enough to be used in a generic method where each member needs to be treated differently.

Comment: Totally get what you're saying I am trying to pass minimal data to an abstract class. Is it possible without having `toGreek` and `toEnglish` being enums, and it being a type like `PureMapping` that is above in the updated question?

Comment: @ThomasReggi I've provided a couple more solutions. Hopefully one of them works for your needs.